# Locating a bin in boost histogram

Tags: c++, boost, histogram

I'm trying out the new boost::histogram library but having trouble with some basic usage.  When adding a new data point to a histogram, I'd like to know the index of the bin it was assigned to.  The method that does the insertion returns void so I'm trying to use STL algorithms to locate the bin but compiler complains.  Here's the code, modified from one of the examples in docs

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include <boost/format.hpp>    // only needed for printing
#include <boost/histogram.hpp> // make_histogram, regular, weight, indexed

namespace bh = boost::histogram;
using namespace std;

int main() {  
  vector<double> v = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};

  auto h = bh::make_static_histogram(bh::axis::variable<>(v.begin(), v.end()));

  vector<double> data = {-0.5, 1.1, 2.3, 3.7, 3.0, 2.999};
  std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ref(h));

  auto it = lower_bound(h.begin(), h.end(), 3.0);
  cout << it.idx(0) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The compiler spits out a bunch of errors but I think boils down to the fact that lower_bound can't do the comparison of the objects.  The library docs seem to imply that STL algorithms are supported. 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
    auto v_test = axis::variable<>{ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 };
    auto h_test = make_histogram(v_test);

    vector<double> data = { -0.5, 1.1, 2.3, 3.7, 3.0, 2.999 };
    std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ref(h_test));

    auto it_test = std::lower_bound(h_test.begin(), h_test.end(), 3.0);
    auto pos_test = (it_test - h_test.begin()) - 1;

    cout << "here is pos" << pos_test << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly use the axis to compute a bin. For example (updated for Boost 1.73):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include <boost/histogram.hpp>

namespace bh = boost::histogram;

int main() {  
  std::vector<double> v = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};

  auto h = bh::make_histogram(bh::axis::variable<>(v));

  std::vector<double> data = {-0.5, 1.1, 2.3, 3.7, 3.0, 2.999};
  h.fill(data);

  auto bin = h.axis(0).index(3.0);
  std::cout << bin << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```